# Auto populate Dropdown jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to make a auto populate dropdown with country names. when user type a letter in editable type div the dropdown will be displayed with matching letters which typed by user. once clicked on any dropdown item it will load to the input area as tag type items with remove X mark & selected item will be removed from dropdown and will be add back it to dropdown when remove the tags. here I am facing two issues the dropdown not showing based on typed letter its showing on focus. second issue, once I selected an item it is adding as tag but not removing typed letter from the input div area. please help me to fix this

```
 <div class="input" contenteditable="true" id="countryInput"></div>
    <div class="multi-eids-dropdown" id="countryDropdown"></div>

.dropdown {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.input {
  border:solid 1px #ddd;
}

 

span .remove {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*=====================================================*/
  .multi-eids {position: relative;}
      .multi-eids-dropdown { position: absolute;
        overflow-y: auto;
      top: 50px; left: 0; width: 100%;
    max-height: 197px; min-height: 60px; 
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
    }
    .eid-item { display: flex; padding: 8px; border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;}
    .eid-item:hover {      background: var(--gray-light);   }
    .eid-item:last-child {border-bottom: none;}
    .userpic {     width: 32px;  height: 32px;     margin: 0 8px 0 0; }
    .eidinfos {line-height: normal;}
    .eidinfos p { margin: 0; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 500;}
    .eidinfos small {font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400;}
    .selected-items { 
       
      /* border: 2px solid var(--grey-ui-grey-700, #b3b2b5); */
    height: 48px;     
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: 8px 0 0 0;
    }
    .selected-item {
      display: inline-flex;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: var(--gray-light);
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
     }
     .selected-item .close {margin: 0 0 0 4px; font-weight: 600; }

$(document).ready(function() {
    const countries = ["USA", "Canada", "UK", "Australia", "France", "Germany", "Japan"];
    
    const $input = $("#countryInput");
    const $dropdown = $("#countryDropdown");
    
    // Populate the dropdown with country items
    function populateDropdown() {
        $dropdown.empty();
        countries.forEach(function(country) {
            if ($input.text().indexOf(country) === -1) {
                const $item = $("<div class='eid-item'>").text(country);
                $item.on("click", function() {
                    addCountryToInput(country);
                    $item.remove();
                });
                $dropdown.append($item);
            }
        });
    }

    function addCountryToInput(country) {
        const $span = $("<span contenteditable='false' class='selected-item'>").text(country);
        const $remove = $("<span class='close'>x</span>");
        
        $remove.on("click", function() {
            $span.remove();
            $dropdown.append($("<div class=''>").text(country).on("click", function() {
                addCountryToInput(country);
                $(this).remove();
            }));
        });
        
        $span.append($remove);
        $input.append($span);
    }

    // Show the dropdown when the user types a letter
    $input.on("input", function() {
        $dropdown.show();
        populateDropdown();
    });

    // Hide the dropdown when clicking outside the input or dropdown
    $(document).on("click", function(event) {
        if (!$input.is(event.target) && !$dropdown.is(event.target) && $dropdown.has(event.target).length === 0) {
            $dropdown.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/anoopsuda/pkfL30gw/16/

Comment: If you use the `[<>]` snippet editor here at SO we do not have to leave to see a [mcve]. The fiddle does not show the list in Chrome until I start typing. It however does not remove what I type before pasting the selected element

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to the scripts. The new code will show all the items of the array in the dropdown when the `input`element gets the focus when user click with mouse or as starts typing. When the element loses focus, the dropdown gets hidden. The code works by managing the letters that are typed by the user.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const countries = ["USA", "Canada", "UK", "Australia", "France", "Germany", "Japan"];

  const $input = $("#countryInput");
  const $dropdown = $("#countryDropdown");

  // Populate the dropdown with country items
  function populateDropdown() {
    $dropdown.empty();
    const inputText = $input.text().trim();
    countries.forEach(function(country) {
      if (country.toLowerCase().includes(inputText.toLowerCase())) {
        const $item = $("<div class='eid-item'>").text(country);
        $item.on("click", function() {
          addCountryToInput(country);
          $item.remove();
        });
        $dropdown.append($item);
      }
    });
  }

  function addCountryToInput(country) {
    const $span = $("<span contenteditable='false' class='selected-item'>").text(country);
    const $remove = $("<span class='close'>x</span");

    $remove.on("click", function() {
      $span.remove();
      $dropdown.append($("<div class='eid-item'>").text(country).on("click", function() {
        addCountryToInput(country);
        $(this).remove();
      }));
    });

    $span.append($remove);
    $input.empty();
    $input.append($span);
  }

  // Show the dropdown when the user types a letter or clicks on the input element
  $input.on("input click", function() {
    $dropdown.show();
    populateDropdown();
  });

  // Hide the dropdown when clicking outside the input or dropdown
  $(document).on("click", function(event) {
    if (!$input.is(event.target) && !$dropdown.is(event.target) && $dropdown.has(event.target).length === 0) {
      $dropdown.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.input {
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}

span .remove {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*=====================================================*/

.multi-eids {
  position: relative;
}

.multi-eids-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 197px;
  min-height: 60px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
}

.eid-item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
}

.eid-item:hover {
  background: var(--gray-light);
}

.eid-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.userpic {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}

.eidinfos {
  line-height: normal;
}

.eidinfos p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.eidinfos small {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.selected-items {
  /* border: 2px solid var(--grey-ui-grey-700, #b3b2b5); */
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.selected-item {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: var(--gray-light);
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.selected-item .close {
  margin: 0 0 0 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="input" contenteditable="true" id="countryInput"></div>
<div class="multi-eids-dropdown" id="countryDropdown"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it meets your requirement

Comment: Thank you for your support, but unfortunately the dropdown loading before typing any letters. and once we select one country name after that  it does not show dropdown second time to select other country name. :( 
https://jsfiddle.net/anoopsuda/t1Lmxaks/2/

Comment: The code is working fine as you wanted. Also, I mentioned it in my commentary above that When the Element Gets focus, all Values will be displayed. Remove `$(document).on("click", function(event) {...}` from the script if you do not want it.
Once You Select a Country, the element is filled with the lettes of that Country. You will need to clear the element to get the whole list again.